# Are we Restricted to put master key single quote ' ' in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am confronting a situation while create a master key in sqlserver 2008 R2.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION
BY PASSWORD='MyStrongPassword';
```

if I create master key using above hard code value 'MyStrongPassword' than it creates perfectly.

If I create master key using dynamic value like given below:

```
declare @mKey varchar(500),@ckey nvarchar(500)

select @mKey =  masterkey,@cKey =certificatekey from ##CertKeys

set @mKey = char(39) + @mKey + char(39)
select @mKey

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = "'+ @mKey + '";
```

It gives me an error:

> incorrect syntax near '+'

Comment: `"'+ @mKey + '"`? MS SQL uses `'` for quoting, not `"`. What is it exactly you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is all wrong. String quotes are `'` in MS SQL, not `"` - in fact, `"` is used for quoting identifiers. In other words, you're trying to access a "column" named `'+ @mKey + '`.

You've already got the `'`s in the string, so just use

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = @mKey;
```

However, this does not work - the statement does not allow the use of variables - only literal strings. This likely has a good reason, so you shouldn't try to circumvent it. However, if you really want to, you can use `sp_executesql` to execute arbitrary SQL, including the statement above:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' 
           + replace(@mKey, '''', '''''') + N''';';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Of course, this is a horrific aberration, and you really shouldn't use it unless absolutely necessary; if it *is* necessary, make sure the possible values always decode properly - this is just an extremely bare-bones "escaping" to ensure that `'` can be used in `@mKey`. Unless you have full control over what can be in `@mKey`, this is likely going to be very dangerous.

Comment: Hi Luaan,Thanks so much for quick response. I've tried this CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = @mKey; already but no success.The above syntax is one of the possible way which i've tried, Please share more thoughts if feasible to you

Comment: @SachinKalia What does it mean, "no success"? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, I got the same error as shown below: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '@mKey'.

Comment: @SachinKalia Oh, okay. The token must be STRING or TEXT_LEX. It's not designed for being used dynamically. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Luaan Yes may be MS SQL has restricted end user to put value dynamically.it only takes string which is enclosed in single quotes only.I am trying to put value (which is a stored in a Global Temp file). I am fetching that value and passing it here using declare @mKey nvarchar(50) format.Which is putting hurdle for me. Actually primary intention is no one can see this value hardcode value in single quote ' '.

Comment: Luaan Sure i'll try with your suggestion and valuable time.Thanks a lots